# Support To Change Link Htaccess in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redirect

I want to change my link from

> http://localhost/laravel/search?keyword=freestyle

To

> http://localhost/laravel/search/freestyle

I tried many ways to change but it didn't work. I hope someone will help me. Thank you

```
public function Search(Request $request){
        $keywords = $request->keyword;

        $search_phim = DB::table("tbl_product")->where('product_name','Like','%'.$keywords.'%')->paginate(24);

         return view('pages.product.search')->with("search_phim",$search_phim);
     }
```

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to update route like:

```
Route::any('/search/{keyword}','XyzController@Search');
```

In the Controller file:

```
   public function Search(Request $request, $keyword){

         $search_phim = DB::table("tbl_product")->where('product_name','Like','%'.$keywords.'%')->paginate(24);

         return view('pages.product.search')->with("search_phim",$search_phim);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much !